# Any way to change the keyboard layout in Typing of the Dead? Or how to type a "#"

Tags: keyboard, the-typing-of-the-dead

I recently read this:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/mavis-beacon-ate-my-brain.html

I installed the game and having been playing it (awesome game!). I already know how to touch type, but I'm going through the tutorials anyway. The tutorials show a keyboard layout that doesn't match mine. That alone wouldn't be a problem (as I said, I already know how to touch type) but it makes it impossible to type `#`. In the keyboard pictured, the `#` appears just to the left of the `Enter` key instead of above the `3`. And during the tutorials, it doesn't register when I type `Shift-3` (it shows the British pound sign there when I press `Shift`). There doesn't seem to be any way to type a `#`.

I guess it thinks I have a different key layout than I do (a British standard keyboard?). Anyway, is there any way to change it to my standard US PC keyboard layout?

If not, is there at least some combination of keys I can press so that the game will register `#`?

Comment: A friend of mine had this game on the Dreamcast years ago, but I had no idea there was a PC port.  I'm not sure if I should thank you or be mad at you.  Either way, I'm not likely to get much done at work today.

Comment: @RESPAWN, if all it takes from you is one workday, you're lucky ;). I can't play at work, but let me tell you, I've been spending half the rest of my time on this game since I've discovered it! I've put in about a dozen hours already. And I'm sure I'll be right back to it again tonight...

Comment: For something so mind-mindbogglingly addictive, it's hard to believe it's helping me improve on an actual valuable real world-skill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm kicking myself now. I just spent half an hour researching this and just now on a whim I re-checked the options menu (which is actually the first thing I checked) and saw a Keyboard option that I was blind to see before. It gives options for "UK" and "US" and it was on the default of "UK".